# Upload file in Android 2.2.1 webview using html form

Tags: android, html, file-upload, android-webview

I'm developing an Android 2.2.1 app using webview. I can not seem to find a working solution for a file upload. It's a standard file upload form. Webview never pops up the browser box. Under the web browser itself, everything works. In webview, no browsing popup. If you know of a solution, please tell me exactly where to place the added code in the android code section.

File upload form below:

```
<form name="form" id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.asp" method="post">
<input id="blob" name="blob" class="simpleinput" type="file" />
</form>
```

Android code below:

```
package com.pic21.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class pic21 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView mWebView;

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.m.blah.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I looked around for a bit more and found code that works using the webChromeClient. Working code below:

```
package com.pic21.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class pic extends Activity {  

 private WebView mWebView;  

 private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;  
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                    Intent intent) {  
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
  {  
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
   Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  
   : intent.getData();  
   mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
   mUploadMessage = null;
  }  
 }  

 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

  mWebView = new WebView(this); 
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.m.blah.com");
  mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 

  {   
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

  mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
  i.setType("image/*");  
  pic21Activity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

         }  
  });  

  setContentView(mWebView);  
 }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
mWebView.goBack();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

> The code for the AndroidManifest.xml file should contain the internet permission

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pic21.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".pic21Activity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```